# Pointing to a tab within a Flex application

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

Does anyone know how I would load up a flex application and on load the application would open on a different tab within the application. The only thing I can think of is sending a parameter into the application to tell it where to go, but how does the app load that tab then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through [Deep Linking](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=deep_linking_2.html).  Basically, you can use the fragment (hash) of the URL to jump to a location in the application.

Comment: The current Flex 4 documentation about deep linking: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cb6.html

Comment: Can you use deeplinking if you dont use states in Flex?

Comment: Yes.  In fact, you can directly control when and how URLs change and how to interpret them.